# How to display a message without html tag with Spring and Thymeleaf

Tags: html, spring, thymeleaf, message

I have some html code:

```
<div class="brand">
    <span class="logo"></span> Title
    <small>subtitle</small>
</div>
```

in  tag I can display text from messages.properties (with locales) in that way (spring + thymeleaf)

```
<small th:text="#{small.text}" />
```

but I don't know how to display proper language version for Title text.

thanks for advice

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to accomplish this is to use [expression inlining](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#inlining).  You can use expressions directly in your html tags, like this:

```
<h1>
    [[#{h1.text}]]
    <small>[[#{small.text}]]</small>
</h1>
```

Depending on the version of thymeleaf your are using, you might have to use the property `th:inline="text"`, like this:

```
<h1 th:inline="text">
    [[#{h1.text}]]
    <small th:inline="text">[[#{small.text}]]</small>
</h1>
```

Comment: I solved with this: [[${h1.text}]]  instead of [[#{h1.text}]]

Answer (score 2):

You can do like that :

```
<div class="brand">
    <span class="logo"></span><span th:text="#{title.text}" th:remove="tag"> Title </span>
    <small th:text="#{small.text}">subtitle</small>
</div>
```

Comment: What in case if we have something like that
<h1>Text <small>another small text</small></h1>?

Answer (score 1):

You can use "th:utext" tag (or data-th-utext) for "unescaped text" and then add some html code and class in a global title text.
With your comment example, you could have :

```
<div class="brand">
    <span class="logo"></span> 
    <h1> 
      <span th:utext=#{title.text}> </span>
    </h1>
</div>
```

With

```
title.text=Title<br/><small>subtitle</small>
```